# Attribute Error 'module' object has no attribute "Field"

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm trying to extend an admin definition of `provide how this field is named in datasource` in `bmihelac/django-import-export` ,and am getting the error `Attribute Error 'module' object has no attribute "Field"` :

in models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField( max_length=50)
    title = models.CharField( max_length=150)
```

in admin.py

```
#admin.py
from blog.models import *
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from import_export import resources
from import_export import fields

class AuthorResource(resources.ModelResource):
    author= fields.Field(column_name='myname')
    class Meta:
        model = Author

class AuthorAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin,admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('author', 'title',)
    list_display = ('author', 'title',)
    resource_class = AuthorResource
```

Thanks for your concern.

The whole trace back

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/blog/author/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('blog',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'suit',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'south',
 'django_select2',
 'suit_redactor',
 'suit_ckeditor',
 'import_export',
 'reversion',
 'django_extensions')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  318.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  346.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  341.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "D:\Documents\GitHub\GoodDjango\GoodDjango\urls.py" in <module>
  7. admin.autodiscover()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py" in autodiscover
  29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py" in import_module
  40.         __import__(name)
File "D:\Documents\GitHub\GoodDjango\blog\admin.py" in <module>
  31. class AuthorResource(resources.ModelResource):
File "D:\Documents\GitHub\GoodDjango\blog\admin.py" in AuthorResource
  32.     author= fields.Field(column_name='myname')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/blog/author/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'Field'
```

Because I import the import_export relevant class and motheds, I can't find out the reason.

Comment: It might be helpful it you provided the complete stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your attention,I paste the traceback above

Comment: The error appears to be generated in line 32 of `admin.py` but the posted code shows the offending code at line 9.  Is it possible that `fields` was redefined somewhere in those missing lines?

Comment: Try importing django-import-export from the command line and see if you can import & instantiate the Field class. That will help you figure out if it's a problem with your installation of that library, or with your code.

Comment: @John1024,thanks,but it's the piece of whole code, and I only use the package in this code

Comment: @RexE,ok I will try your mothod to solve it ,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check if You have file: `__init__.py` in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\import_export\`

If You are using `virtualenv` it seams that it hasn't been activated.

Also You have and error here:

```
class AuthorAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('author', 'title',)
    list_display = ('author', 'title',)
    resource_class = AuthorResource
```

because ImportExportModelAdmin already has ModelAdmin:

```
class ImportExportModelAdmin(ImportExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    Subclass of ModelAdmin with import/export functionality.
    """
```