# django-import-export admin: how to export model name in a Many to Many relationship

Tags: python, django

Given the models:

```
#models.py
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, through = 'AuthorBook')

class AuthorBook(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    book =  models.ForeignKey(Book)
    some_info = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

and

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author, Book, AuthorBook
from import_export.admin import ExportMixin
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ManyToManyWidget

class BookResource(resources.ModelResource):
    author = fields.Field(widget=ManyToManyWidget(Author))
    class Meta(object):
        model = Book
        exclude = ('id',)

    def dehydrate_author(self,Author):
        return Author.name
```

When I try to export the data on Book's Admin panel I'm getting the error:

> 'Book' object has no attribute 'name'

I'm stuck in this for hours, and the closest answer I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317148/attribute-error-module-object-has-no-attribute-field), but did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying that your model is Book, which has no name attribute. I'm guessing your function dehydrate_livro() is being called with a book as a parameter, which you are misleadingly calling Author (just because a variable starts with an uppercase letter doesn't make it an instance of any class). Your method is then trying to access the name attribute in this book, `Author.name`, but there is none.

Try:

```
def dehydrate_livro(self,book):
    return book.author.all()
```

This will return a list of your book's authors.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the reply! Actually, I made a mistake on the first post, now that i edited it, can you read it one more time? (changes in admin.py)... With your code, i got  - 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'objects'

Comment: Thank you! the book.author.all()[0] didn't work(list index out of range), but book.author.first() did! The problem now is that if the book has more than 1 authors, it only shows the first

Comment: But this way it goes "Unexpected data type <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>"

Comment: I have no idea how you're calling your function or what you're trying to do with the result. The more context you give the more people will be able to help you in the future.